# Service broker - Poison messages handling - event handle

Tags: sql-server-2012, service-broker, eventhandler

I am trying to get notification when a poison message get my Queue disabled and followed the following post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/06/30/poison-message-handling.aspx

SQL Server : SQL 2012

Once set up, i've tried the configuration and i see the following in my log:
first message :

Closed event notification conversation endpoint with handle '{AF43B2F1-27A6-E411-9464-028946455A17}', due to the following error: '`-8490`Cannot find the remote service '[QueueDisabledNotifService]' because it does not exist.'.

Second Message : 
Failure to send an event notification instance of type 'BROKER_QUEUE_DISABLED' on conversation handle '{AF43B2F1-27A6-E411-9464-028946455A17}'. Error Code = '8429'.

Third Message : 
Event notification 'QueueDisabledNotif' in database 'XXX' dropped due to send time service broker errors. Check to ensure the conversation handle, service broker contract, and service specified in the event notification are active.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Doron

Comment: Run [ssbdiagnose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450(v=sql.110).aspx) to find any configuration errors

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear as it could be without some code. When poison messages occur and the queue is disabled service broker issues a Broker:Queue Disabled event. You could look into catching this in your code (From there you should look into ending the conversation to get rid of the message).

similar question here:

[SQL Server Broker Transaction Completed on Poison Message Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515101/sql-server-broker-transaction-completed-on-poison-message-exception)

(with code)